# Execute Java from command line

Tags: java, unix, command-line

I have a folder on my desktop titled "Stuff" and in that folder I have the following:

- Hello.java
- mail.jar

And Hello.java imports from mail.jar, so I need to tell Hello.java to look for mail.jar.

From a Windows command line and from a unix command line, how can I compile this and run this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Compile:

```
javac -cp .;mail.jar Hello.java
```

where `;` is for Windows; use `:` for *nix.

and run:

```
java -cp .;mail.jar Hello
```

where again, use `;` for Windows and `:` for *nix.

`-cp` tells both `javac` and `java` what **classpath** to use, and as your files are in the local directory where you're executing the command, you can use `.` for the Hello part and the name of the jar for the paths inside the jar. Wikipedia has a [decent article on classpaths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath).

Mind you, if you're going to be doing this on a regular basis, you may want to set your `CLASSPATH` environment variable rather than constantly using the `-cp` flag. Both `java` and `javac` use the `CLASSPATH` variable.

For my own development machine, I actually include `.` in my `CLASSPATH` variable, for convenience. It's not something I would do on a production or build/test box, but it's very handy for development purposes. You'd want to have your usual jars in it as well.

Comment: This will not make Java pick up the JAR file.

Comment: @Jesper: Thanks, I think I was fixing that as you commented. :-) I'd kind of forgotten the jar.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Hello.java does not contain a package declaration, on Windows:

```
javac -cp mail.jar Hello.java
java -cp mail.jar;. Hello
```

The only difference on Unix platforms is that you separate the elements of the classpath with a scolon instead of a semicolon:

```
java -cp mail.jar:. Hello
```

Answer (score -1):

Follow this tutorial and you should be able to do it in no time:

[Java Compilation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html)

You also shouldn't have any problems with the classpath because your classes are in the same folder